# Проверка пароля на соответствие условиям

Tags: python, пароль

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помочь в решении задания. По 3 и 4 заданию для самостоятельной проверки выходит сообщение

> 'Ошибка. Запрещенный спецсимвол'

из кода, хотя должен давать рекомендации для его усиления. Как корректно сравнить символы из введённого пароля со всеми допустимыми символами?

Пробовал через

```
cond5=all(char in set(password) for char in set(acceptable))
```

(далее `if all(cond5) is False`, в коде использовал вариант ниже с `result`)
или

```py
result=[]
for x in p:
    result.append(x in a)
```

и все равно результат получается `False`, хотя каждый из символов `Q123wer123tY` содержится в допустимых символах

```
password=input('Введите пароль:')
digits='1234567890'
upper_letters='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
lower_letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
symbols='!@#$%^&*()-+'
message="Слабый пароль.Рекомендации:"
acceptable=upper_letters+lower_letters+symbols
cond1=(len(password))>11
cond2=all(char in password for char in symbols)
cond3=all(char in password for char in upper_letters)
cond4=all(char in password for char in digits)
cond5=all(char in set(password) for char in set(acceptable))
rules=[cond1,cond2,cond3,cond4,сond5]
p=set(password)
a=set(acceptable)
result=[]

for x in p:
    result.append(x in a)
if all(result) is False:
    print('Ошибка. Запрещенный спецсимвол')
elif all(result) is True:
    if cond1 is False:
        message+=' увеличить число символов -'+" "+str(12-len(password))+','      
    if cond2 is False:
        message+=' '+'добавить 1 спецсимвол,'
    if cond3 is False:
        message+=' '+'добавить 1 заглавную букву,'
    if cond4 is False:
        message+=' '+'добавить 1 цифру,'
        print(message[:(len(message)-1)])
else:
    if all(rules) is True:
        print('Сильный пароль')
```

Comment: `acceptable=upper_letters+lower_letters+symbols` - а про `digits` забыли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли `digits`  включить в `acceptable`. Ну и с проверками чего-то намудрено.

```
def check_password(password):
    #password = input('Введите пароль:')
    digits = '1234567890'
    upper_letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    lower_letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    symbols = '!@#$%^&*()-+'
    acceptable = digits+upper_letters+lower_letters+symbols

    passwd = set(password)
    if any(char not in acceptable for char in passwd):
        print('Ошибка. Запрещенный спецсимвол')
    else:
        recommendations = []
        if len(password) < 12:
            recommendations.append(f'увеличить число символов - {12-len(password)}')
        for what, message in ((digits,        'цифру'),
                              (symbols,       'спецсимвол'),
                              (upper_letters, 'заглавную букву'),
                              (lower_letters, 'строчную букву')):
            if all(char not in what for char in passwd):
                recommendations.append(f'добавить 1 {message}')

        if recommendations:
            print("Слабый пароль. Рекомендации:", ", ".join(recommendations))
        else:
            print('Сильный пароль.')
            
#tests
for test in ("qwety", "Qwert_Y", "Q123wer123tY", "A^B@C*D", "@PowerRangers123@"):
    print("Password:", test)
    check_password(test)
    print()
```

*(Оформлено в функцию исключительно ради тестов.)*

> Password: qwety
> Слабый пароль. Рекомендации: увеличить число символов - 7, добавить 1 цифру, добавить 1 спецсимвол, добавить 1 заглавную букву
>
> Password: Qwert_Y
> Ошибка. Запрещенный спецсимвол
>
> Password: Q123wer123tY
> Слабый пароль. Рекомендации: добавить 1 спецсимвол
>
> Password: A^B@C*D
> Слабый пароль. Рекомендации: увеличить число символов - 5, добавить 1 цифру, добавить 1 строчную букву
>
> Password: @PowerRangers123@
> Сильный пароль.